# Fastify: ts-node shoot error Property 'foo' does not exist on type 'FastifyInstance<...>'

Tags: typescript, fastify

I'm making a fastify plugin using fastify decorator. Following is my sample code.

```js
import { FastifyPluginAsync } from 'fastify';
import fp from 'fastify-plugin';

interface RegistFooOptions {
  barValue: string;
}

const registFooPlugin: FastifyPluginAsync<RegistFooOptions> = async (
  fastify,
  options
) => {
  fastify.decorate('foo', {
    bar: options.barValue,
  });
};

export default fp(registFooPlugin);
```

And I use it in `server.ts` like

```js
fastify.register(registFooPlugin, {
 barValue: 'bar!',
});
```

Following the [comment](https://github.com/fastify/fastify/issues/1417#issuecomment-458601746), I also defined the `@types/index.d.ts`

```js
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars */
import fastify from 'fastify';

declare module 'fastify' {
  export interface FastifyInstance<
    HttpServer = Server,
    HttpRequest = IncomingMessage,
    HttpResponse = ServerResponse
  > {
    foo: {
      bar: string;
    };
  }
}
```

Then, I could use the decorated value `foo.bar` in fastify route like below

```js
interface IBody {...}
fastify.post<{ Body: IBody }>('/', async function (request, reply) {
    const {...} = request.body;
    const barValue = await this.foo.bar;

    console.log(barValue); // expect to show 'bar!'

    return { success: true };
  });
```

it means that **there is no typescript lint error**.

**But when I run server with ts-node the following error occurred**

`Property 'foo' does not exist on type 'FastifyInstance<Server, IncomingMessage, ServerResponse, FastifyLoggerInstance>'`

How can I fix this error ?? :(

additional:
my tsconf is following

```json
{
  "display": "Node 12",

  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["es2019", "es2020.promise", "es2020.bigint", "es2020.string"],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es2019",

    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
  }
}
```

Comment: What does your tsconfig look like?

Comment: @Yeysides I edit the qustion with tsconfig ! thanks :)

Comment: Try adding `typeRoots: ['@types']` to your tsconfig

Comment: @Yeysides not works... but when I run ts-node with `ts-node --transpile-only server.ts` it works.

Comment: @wallah any luck on this?